# How to run maven jar from target directory

Tags: java, maven, configuration, directory

I have this project structure:

```
|--Node
|-----pom.xml
|-----resources
|-----src
```

On compilation i get:

```
|--Node
|-----resources
|-----src
|-----pom.xml
|-----**target**
|--------**resources**
|--------**Node.jar**
```

I want to run Node.jar **from IntelliJ** and that it will take resources from the resources folder within target.

I tried defining:

```
JAR_PATH = Constants.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

And also

```
JAR_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir").replace('\\','/') + "/Node.jar";
```

The problem is that with the 1st method, I get the directory of the Constants class (which is compiled separately and is another different Module).

In the 2nd option i get the Node directory, and not Node.target directory which is the directory I want.

What are the option to achieve what I want? 
Is there any way to make maven run from the target directory, and not the directory in which the pom.xml is located?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to achieve. Something like `java -jar target/Node.jar`?

Comment: Yes, I want that it will be from IntelliJ.
My maven run configuration is:
`exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.path.to.node.Main`
When I run the code the cwd is from Node folder, and not target folder. I want it to be from in the target folder.

Comment: Are you looking for the option [workingDirectory](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#workingDirectory) to set the current working directory?

Comment: Hey. Thanks a lot for your comment, but this only works on exec:exec and not exec:java

Comment: Could you please provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's still not really clear what you want to achive. Because `java -jar target/Node.jar` executes the main class (stored in the `Node.jar` archive) which is defined in the contained `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. Whereas  `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=...` executes the main class from within `target/classes`. How do you access a file in `resources/`?